# show one list item at a time - Android

Tags: android

There is list of names and I want to show one name at a time on mobile screen and slide the activity to see another name. Tried using viewpager but succeeded in showing only one textview for multiple times, not geeting how to implement list in viewpager.

Comment: post your code...

Answer (score 1):

You have to make custom adapter for that purpose , which will have your array list and it will populate your data into TextView.

First make **Custom Adapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
// Declare Variables

Context context;
int[] flag;
LayoutInflater inflater;
int pos;
public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context,  int[] flag) {
    this.context = context;
    this.flag = flag;
}
public ViewPagerAdapter (Context context, int[] flag, int position ){
    this.context = context;
    this.flag = flag;
    this.pos = position;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return flag.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    // Declare Variables

    TextView txt;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);
    // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
    txt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
    // Capture position and set to the ImageView
    txt.setText(flag[position]);
    txt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {            
       }
    });
    // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

    return itemView;
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
 }
}
```

Now add adapter to your viewPager like this

```
  adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Image.this, flag );//Here Flag is array
  viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(possition);
```

Hope this helps